# How can I reproduce this table with LaTeX?

Tags: tables

I an new to LaTeX and I am trying to reproduce a table, but I do not manage to create what I want, it either does not fit the page (goes beyond the borders), or for some reason does not work with text in bold and italics. Below is a picture from Word, the table should look something like that.
Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you share the code that does not work with us? Maybe we can tell you why it goes beyond the borders or does not work with italics and bold.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way with `tabularx` and `makecell` to add some vertical padding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\newcommand{\nl}{\newline}

\begin{document}

{\setcellgapes{5pt}\makegapedcells
\centering\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
  \hline
  \emph{Direct Speech}: & \emph{Indirect Speech}: \\
  She said, \textbf{‘I’ll come} back \textbf{here} to meet \textbf{you} again \textbf{tomorrow’}
                        &
  She said \textbf{that} she \textbf{would go} back \textbf{there} to see \textbf{him} again \textbf{the following day}
  \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\emph{Free Indirect Style}: } \\
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{She said \textbf{she would come} back \textbf{here} to see \textbf{him} again\textbf{ tomorrow}} \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Is the below code helps you?

```
\documentclass[openany,10pt]{book}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}|p{10pc}|p{10pc}|@{}}
\hline
\centerline{\textit{Direct Speech:}} &\centerline{\textit{Indirect
Speech:}}\\
\hline
She said, ... &She said that ...\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\centering Free Indirect style}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not abuse `\centerline`...